# Simplification of this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt{e^{2x} + e^{-2x} + 2}$ which the solution says simplifies to $ \int_0^1 e^{-x}(e^{2x} + 1)$. I understand the simplification but what happened to the constant $\sqrt{2}$? It's been awhile since I've done any computational math stuff so maybe it's just something dumb I'm missing. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Use $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2 ab$

Comment: $e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2 = (e^x + e^{-x})^2$.

Comment: Thanks I see it now. Silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2=(e^x+e^{-x})^2$ we have $$\int_0^1\sqrt{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}\;dx=\int_0^1\left(e^{x}+e^{-x}\right)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$2\cosh (2x)=e^{2x}+e^{-2x} $$

$$1+\cosh(2x)=2\cosh^2 (x) $$

the integral becomes
$$\int \sqrt {4\cosh^2 (x)}dx=\int 2\cosh (x)dx$$
$$=\int (e^x+e^{-x})dx=\int e^{-x}(e^{2x}+1)dx $$

$$= (e^x-e^{-x})+C=2\sinh (x)+C $$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, take $e^{-2x}$ out:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{e^{-2x}}\sqrt{(e^{4x}+2e^{2x}+1)}dx=\int_0^1 e^{-x}\sqrt{(e^{2x}+1)^2}dx=\int_0^1 e^{-x}(e^{2x}+1)dx.$$